# Find file with extension csv using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file

**I want to find a file with .csv extension in a folder.**

```
My batch file is also in the same folder
I tried

for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*.csv) do set p=%%~dpnxa

But i am getting the output along with the folder full path.
Ex:- z:\folbat\abcd.csv
```

**I dont want the full path, I only want the file name**

```
Output:-
abcd.csv
```

**Please Help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `%%~dpnxa` you explicitely tell cmd to return: **d**rive, **p**ath, **n**ame and e**x**tension of your file.

If you want the name and extension only, use

```
%%~nxa
```

(described id `for/?`)

Comment: How can i get latest modified csv file name?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /od *.csv') do set latest=%%i`

Comment: it is not working, it showing 0 Dir(s) 24,*** bytes free

Comment: ups - `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /od *.csv') do set latest=%%i`

Comment: Thanks Stephan, Appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

So, if `p` is the full path, you can extract the filename by:

```
FOR %%i IN ("%p%") DO (
    set filename=%%~ni%%~xi
)
```